# difference between axis-wsdl4j and wsdl4j

Tags: java, wsdl4j

what is the difference between the following libraries?

```
<dependency org="axis" name="axis-wsdl4j" rev="1.5.1"/>
<dependency org="wsdl4j" name="wsdl4j" rev="1.5.1"/>
```

I briefly compared the downloaded class binaries and they look the same. But why multiple names?

Comment: my ivy dependency elements were removed from the post...I am comparing axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar and wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar

Comment: Hm, according to `md5sum`, `axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar` is the same file as `wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar`. Now to wonder why, and sort out the licence (which is conveniently **not** included in `wsdl4j-1.5.1-sources.jar`)…

Comment: Appears to correspond to `wsdl4j-1_5_1` tag of [this repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/wsdl4j/code/?source=navbar) (wsdl4j project at Sourcefrog), modulo LF vs. CR-LF line endings. That’d make it `CPL 1.0` licenced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

axis:axis-wsdl4j appears to be the exact same distribution as wsdl4j:wsdl4j. looking at versions released to maven central for both [wsdl4j](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22wsdl4j%22%20AND%20a%3a%22wsdl4j%22) and [axis-wsdl4j](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22axis%22%20AND%20a%3a%22axis-wsdl4j%22) it looks like axis had to upload the wsdl4j artifacts themselves because wsdl4j didnt publish anything between 1.0 and 1.4 to maven central, but stopped doing so after 1.5.1 (both published 1.5.1 - axis a bit earlier - but only the wsdl4j:wsdl4j artifact has seen any regular updates since).

in terms of code they are the [same code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/)

it looks like axis started packaging wsdl4j themselves [in version 1.1](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/changelogs/1_1.html):

> We include a more recent version of wsdl4j.jar (23/mar/2003)

but will stop doing so [when 1.4.1 is out](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/changelogs/1_4_1.html)

> WSDL4J has been upgraded from 1.5.1 to 1.6.2

the license for wsdl4j (in both distributions is the Common Public License - v 1.0) - in /lib/wsdl4j-1.5.1.LICENSE in the [axis 1.4 source distribution](http://apache.mivzakim.net/axis/axis/java/1.4/axis-src-1_4.zip). thats also the license in the sourceforge page for the project.